# Correct way adding External classes to Custom Post type and output their methods to template

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, posts, post-class

So I'm creating Custom Post Type, and I have 3 external classes with namespace Test\Events\Model;
Those 3 classes are final class Location, final class Event, and final class Person. Example of method:

```php
public function street(): string
    {
        return 'Street name 2';
    }`
```

For template, I'm using single-event.php. 
My question is, How to hook all those classes and their methods? Everything I have tried it's not working, so I'm missing something for sure.

Thank you all!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by how to hook all those classes and their methods? **Can you give a specific example of hooking a specific method on a specific class into a specific hook?** A custom post type is a post that has a different value in the `type` column in the database, there is no OO representation, just the standard `WP_Post` which is just a data container with no logic. If you're looking for an interface to implement or an object to extend, there is none, that's not how WP dev works. Also what have you tried?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell Thank you for commenting.

Comment: @Tom J Nowell Thank you for commenting.Im Creating a Custom post type OOP way. i tried with add_action and also with add_filter. $loc = Location:street(); add_filter('str',$loc); and then called in template as apply_filters('str','street'); but I get an Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'Musterstraße 2' not found or invalid function name ( which is a return string from method that is called);  Same if I do add_action('str',$loc->street()); where $loc = Location();

Comment: hmmm I recommend looking up `callable`'s on php.net, `add_filter` is expecting a `callable` value, which is a core PHP thing, not a WordPress thing. I'm also unfamiliar with the `str` filter, there is no such filter in core WordPress. Otherwise what you're doing is not how custom post types are normally done. Sure you can create an object that helps but it's literally just a PHP object, there's no special stuff related to custom post types that you can use or work with here

Comment: @Tom J Nowell Thank you very much